# multiple bootstrap 4 carousel changes only the first slide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have got 3 carousel using this, when i click next only the first carousel works even if i click next or previous on 2nd carousel it slides only the first slide. Please help

```
<div class="img-container" >
   <div class="mem-carousel carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
      <div class="carousel-inner" >
         <div class="carousel-item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="img in space.images">
            <img ng-src="{{img}}" style="width:400px; height: 200px;">
         </div>
         <div class="favorite-block price">
            <span class="price-text-left"><font><font>Rs {{space.hourly_rate}}</font></font></span>
            <span class="price-text-right">
               <div><font><font>per</font></font></div>
               <div><font><font>hour</font></font></div>
            </span>
         </div>
         <a class="carousel-control-prev" href=".mem-carousel"  role="button" data-slide="prev">
             <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
         <a class="carousel-control-next" href=".mem-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
             <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>      
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure that you have not used same `id` for all the carousel.

Comment: i am using ng-repeat i knew somewhere i had to change the reference id but how to could it be changed dynamically

Comment: you need to add $index while refering to the class.
change href=".mem-carousel" to href=".mem-carousel{{$index}}" also you need to add mem-carousel{{$index}} at the begining of the carousel